# No me anda reCaptcha de google, que tengo mal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, recaptcha

Básicamente no me anda el reCaptcha, sale que la clave está mal, lógicamente la clave no la puedo compartir, pero me parece que no hay error, la copié 10 veces con un copy paste ambas claves, la secreta y la de sitio y me sale el cartel Error para el propietario del sitio web: el tipo de clave no es válido.

Que estoy haciendo mal? Les adjunto mi formulario de contacto en html junto con el script de php de envío del correo y el catpcha y el javascript donde también trabaja con el captcha.

Abajo de todo donde van los documentos añadidos tengo esto último en el html:

```
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script> <!-- Custom scripts -->
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Este es el formulario en la web en html:

```
<div class="form-container">
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control-input" id="cname" name="name" required>
            <label class="label-control" for="cname">Nombre</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control-input" id="cemail" name="email" required>
            <label class="label-control" for="cemail">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control-textarea" id="cmessage" name="message" required></textarea>
            <label class="label-control" for="cmessage">Su mensaje</label>
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MI_CLAVE_DE_SITIO"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" id="g-recaptcha-response">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="form-control-submit-button">ENVIAR</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Este es el php que envía:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Verifica el reCAPTCHA
    $recaptcha_secret = 'MI_CLAVE_SECRETA';
    $recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $recaptcha = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$recaptcha_secret}&response={$recaptcha_response}");
    $recaptcha = json_decode($recaptcha);
    
    if ($recaptcha->success) {
    // El reCAPTCHA se ha resuelto correctamente, procesa el formulario
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
      
    $to = "EMAIL_DONDE_RECIBO_CORREOS";
    $subject = "Nuevo mensaje de " . $name;
    $body = "Nombre: " . $name . "\n\nCorreo electrónico: " . $email . "\n\nMensaje: " . $message;
      
    // Envía el correo electrónico
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
        // Muestra una alerta de JavaScript si el correo electrónico se envió correctamente
        echo '<script>alert("Mensaje enviado correctamente");</script>';
    } else {
        // Muestra una alerta de JavaScript si hubo un error al enviar el correo electrónico
        echo '<script>alert("Hubo un error al enviar el mensaje. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.");</script>';
    }
    } else {
    // El reCAPTCHA no se ha resuelto correctamente, muestra una alerta de JavaScript
    echo '<script>alert("Por favor, verifica que eres humano.");</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

En el archivo scripts.js tengo lo siguiente:

```
function submitForm() {
    // Obtiene los valores del formulario
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value.trim();
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value.trim();
    var recaptcha = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value.trim();

    // Valida los campos requeridos
    if (name === '' || email === '' || message === '' || recaptcha === '') {
        alert('Por favor, completa todos los campos y verifica que eres humano.');
        return false;
    }

    // Crea una instancia de XMLHttpRequest
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Configura la solicitud HTTP POST
    xhr.open('POST', 'sendemail.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // Maneja el resultado de la solicitud
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            // Muestra una alerta de JavaScript si el correo electrónico se envió correctamente
            alert("Mensaje enviado correctamente");
            // Limpia el formulario
            document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();
            // Reinicia el reCAPTCHA
            grecaptcha.reset();
        } else if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status !== 200) {
            // Muestra una alerta de JavaScript si hubo un error al enviar el correo electrónico
            alert("Hubo un error al enviar el mensaje. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo más tarde.");
        }
    };

    // Envía la solicitud HTTP POST con los datos del formulario
    xhr.send('name=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&email=' + encodeURIComponent(email) + '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message) + '&g-recaptcha-response=' + encodeURIComponent(recaptcha));

    return false;
}
```

Vale aclarar que mi conocimiento en todo esto no es muy avanzado, resolví todo mirando cosas por internet, por eso quizá tengo algo mal y no lo veo.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas, te comento un poco los cambios que yo haría.

Por lo que veo intentas implementar el reCAPTCHA V2 y la verdad que hoy en día ya te recomiendo usar el V3 ya que es más cómodo para la gente, pero bueno según Google son compatibles entre ellos así que puedes cambiar muy rápido entre ellos.

También decirte que es mejor usar la versión Enterprise, te dejo el link:
[reCAPTCHA Enterprise](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha)

Respecto a tu implementación parece estar todo correcto no entiendo muy bien por que te sale ese error, he implementado todo lo que tienes y me sale también, he probado a cambiar a la V3 y funciona pero en la V2 no así que dicho esto te dejo un ejemplo por si quieres implementar dicha versión
Enterprise.

```html
<div class="form-container">
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control-input" id="cname" name="name" required>
        <label class="label-control" for="cname">Nombre</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control-input" id="cemail" name="email" required>
        <label class="label-control" for="cemail">Email</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control-textarea" id="cmessage" name="message" required></textarea>
        <label class="label-control" for="cmessage">Su mensaje</label>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="g-recaptcha-response" id="g-recaptcha-response">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button id="btn-send-form" type="button" data-action='send_email'>ENVIAR</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <script src="./js/scripts.js"></script> <!-- Custom scripts -->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=site-publickey"></script>
    <script>
      let button = document.getElementById('btn-send-form');
      button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(function () {
          grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('site-publickey', { action: button.dataset.action }).then(function (token) {
            // Obtenemos el elemento y le agregamos el token
            let recaptcha = document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response');
            recaptcha.value = token;

            // Hacemos el submit del formulario
            document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        });
      })
    </script>
</div>
```

Solo con lo que ves en el fragmento de código y sin tener que modificar tu fichero `sendmail.php` debería funcionar.

Comment: Podría probar el enterprise.. de todas maneras  estoy usando el recaptcha v3...no sé de donde dedujiste que estaría usando el v2